# Backbone View render: fetch-first versus render-first, both approaches have faults?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

This is more of a conceptual/architectural question than anything; the typical/popular approach to constructing and instantiating Backbone Views seems to be to only render the View AFTER successfully `fetch`ing necessary Model/Collection data from the server (in a `success()` or `done()` callback).

This is all well and good, but what if you have some sort of loading indicator or UI element within the View's template that needs to be displayed before/during the `fetch`? By not rendering the View until the call finishes, you effectively are unable to display such notifications to the user.

Conversely, if you render the View BEFORE making the `fetch`, you're now able to display such UI elements, but you now run the risk of displaying a mostly-empty template, since your Model/Collection data hasn't been retrieved yet, and this can look rather weird.

What if you need both things: UI notifications before/during the `fetch`, AND not to render a mostly-empty template pre-`fetch`? What might be some good approaches towards accomplishing this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a separate loading view to handle the loading gif that listens for relevant events I trigger from the model/collection fetching results. The view responsible for rendering does so without being concerned about the loading gif. The loading gif essentially obscures the results which are "revealed" when the loading gif is removed:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function () {
        // do whatever you need to here
    }
});

var LoadingView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#loading',

    initialize: function () {

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'fetchStarted', this.showLoader);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'fetchFinished', this.hideLoader);
    },

    showLoader: function () {

        var self = this;

        if (this.waitHandle) {
            clearTimeout(this.waitHandle);
            delete this.waitHandle;
        }
        this.waitHandle = setTimeout(function () {
             self.$el.removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
     },

     hideLoader: function () {

         clearTimeout(this.waitHandle);
         delete waitHandle;
         this.$el.addClass('hide');
    }
});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

     getResults: function () {

         var self = this;

         this.fetch({
             beforeSend: function () {
                 self.trigger('fetchStarted');
             },
             complete: function () {
                 self.trigger('fetchFinished');
             }
          });
      }
});
```

I use the timeouts in the loading view to delay showing the loading gif in case they aren't necessary.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, as it appears that a separate Loading View is the common solution here. A few questions, though: 1.) Does the Loading View get REPLACED by the actual View when the data is fetched, or is it totally separate, residing elsewhere in the app/DOM? 2.) Why attach the collection to the Loading View? Doesn't this mean you'd have to reassign the collection if you used the Loading View elsewhere in the app? Why not just trigger the Loading View method from the actual View's fetch?

Comment: 1.) the LoadingView el is an absolutely positioned div (with the loading gif as a background image) that hides the data until it itself is hidden 2.) the collection is attached to the loading view so the view can listen to events from the collection - you can reference any number of collections from the same view if you wish - you could extend the LoadingView class for other collections as well if you wanted to handle other areas of the app separately - as far as triggering it from the rendering view, I have different views that render on data being fetched and I don't want to duplicate code

Answer (score 2):

I usually have an application-level view that will show a loader when it knows one of the app's main collections is being fetched. In face I usually do an ajax before filter to always pop the loader, and hide on completion application wide. It blocks the whole UI, but that's fine unless I'm doing a more complex dashboard-type app where there are clear modular concerns.

Comment: This is the same solution I've come across; an app-wide loading indicator. Unfortunately, it still doesn't really solve the problem at hand - I may still want a page/View-specific loading indicator. All of them being global/app-wide seems suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post with a solution that could interest you (http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/). Basically, one approach to the problem:

1. Store the return value of the fetch call (which is a jQuery promise)
2. Render the loading view (with `MyApp.myRegion.show(loadingView);`)
3. If you want, you can already instantiate your view (that requires data) at this point
4. When the promise is fulfilled (i.e. the fetch is done), display your data-dependent view within the region (as above)